# Public facing enterprise website on any version of Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, office-365, 2016, 2019

We are looking to develop a new public facing CMS on a Sharepoint version. On-prem or cloud. We currently have a public website on SP2013 and believe that SP2013 is end of support 4/2023 and that no other SP version is supported for public facing.

Could the community give any guidance on currently supported SP versions that would be able to have a public facing CMS? We are not considering document management in this question: only information for a public facing website with no document management capability is being requested.

Any links to Microsoft documentation supporting the ability to have an public facing CMS is appreciated, as well as any that say it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Public-Facing Websites are available in SharePoint Server 2019 (On-Premises) but obsoleted in SharePoint Online.

You can Surely create a Public-Facing Website using the SharePoint Server 2019 by following the below steps:

1. Create a Web Application (Anonymous Access Enabled - if required).
2. Create Site Collection with Publishing Portal template.

Do not forget to Enable/Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Feature.

[For Details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-publishing-enabled-site-templates-b4fa3dcd-f4cc-4820-aa73-fed106965725)